# BioPython: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, biopython, fasta, fastq

I'm trying to convert a FASTQ (generated from a Illumina Miseq mate paired genome sequence) file to FASTA and eventually convert that to Genbank using an annotated reference sequence. I'm following instrucitons from the Biopython Tutorial. Here's my code and error.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
records = SeqIO.parse("~/Users/ryanjhope/Documents/PhD/DNA_Sequences/Genome/C. aceto_∆pyrE_∆bcd_Deepseq/YZ1_S11_L001_R1_001.fastq", "fastq")
count = SeqIO.write(records, "~/Users/ryanjhope/Documents/PhD/DNA_Sequences/Genome/C. aceto_∆pyrE_∆bcd_Deepseq/∆bcdpseudo.fasta", "fasta")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ryanjhope/Documents/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 468, in write
    with as_handle(handle, mode) as fp:
  File "/Users/ryanjhope/Documents/anaconda/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/Users/ryanjhope/Documents/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/File.py", line 90, in as_handle
    with open(handleish, mode, **kwargs) as fp:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Users/ryanjhope/Documents/PhD/DNA_Sequences/Genome/C. aceto_\xe2\x88\x86pyrE_\xe2\x88\x86bcd_Deepseq/\xe2\x88\x86bcdpseudo.fasta'
```

Comment: This error is straight forward. The path or file you provided does not exist.

Comment: It does. I copied and pasted the path from finder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback is your friend:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Users/ryanjhope ...
```

and further up:

```
File "/Users/ryanjhope/Documents/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/File.py", line 90, in as_handle
```

This is `'~/Users/`  vs. '/Users/`

Changes these lines:

```
records = SeqIO.parse("~/Users/ryanjhope/Documents/PhD/DNA_Sequences/Genome/C. aceto_∆pyrE_∆bcd_Deepseq/YZ1_S11_L001_R1_001.fastq", "fastq")
count = SeqIO.write(records, "~/Users/ryanjhope/Documents/PhD/DNA_Sequences/Genome/C. aceto_∆pyrE_∆bcd_Deepseq/∆bcdpseudo.fasta", "fasta")
```

into:

```
records = SeqIO.parse("/Users/ryanjhope/Documents/PhD/DNA_Sequences/Genome/C. aceto_∆pyrE_∆bcd_Deepseq/YZ1_S11_L001_R1_001.fastq", "fastq")
count = SeqIO.write(records, "/Users/ryanjhope/Documents/PhD/DNA_Sequences/Genome/C. aceto_∆pyrE_∆bcd_Deepseq/∆bcdpseudo.fasta", "fasta")
```

and try again.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll look at that. I'm obviously a complete novice so I don't even know how to properly interpret the returned error descriptions with certainty that I'm understanding it properly. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Okay, I'm not getting an error but my terminal isn't doing anything. Hopefully its processing the script.

Comment: Oh god. I now have a giant FASTA file :)

Comment: You will see output only if  you use `print()` somewhere in your code. This is different from the interactive prompt, i.e. `>>>`.

Comment: You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer that solves your problem.